# Existence of the conditional tail mean

Tags: conditional-expectation, moments, pareto-distribution

Does the existence of the first moment of a generalized Pareto distribution with support $[0,\infty)$ imply the existence (finiteness) of the conditional tail mean -- i.e. what in risk management is known as expected shortfall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the conditional tail mean is here defined as 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X \mid X\geq x_\alpha]
\end{equation}
for some constant $x_\alpha>0$. Then, by law of total expectation,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{P}(X<x_\alpha)\,\mathbb{E}[X \mid X< x_\alpha] + \mathbb{P}(X\geq x_\alpha)\,\mathbb{E}[X  \mid X\geq x_\alpha].
\end{equation}
The first term is finite since $\mathbb{E}[X \mid X< x_\alpha]$ is bounded from above by $x_\alpha$. Thus, the left hand side is finite if and only if the second term on the right hand side is finite. As $\mathbb{P}(X\geq x_\alpha)$ is a (strictly) positive real number, we conclude that $\mathbb{E}[X \mid X\geq x_\alpha]$ is finite if and only $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is finite.